# How can I make a loop in JSP page with dynamic name in variable?

Tags: jsp, variables, loops, arraylist, jstl

I'm trying to execute a loop getting the data from an ArrayList which is has the following format:

ArrayList Names:

```
Field1     Field2  Field3  Filed4  Field5  Field6  Field7  Filed8  Field9  Field10
TESTName   Laura   James   Ricky   Paul    Andrea  Peter   Michael Tom     Zoe
```

This ArrayList has been generated from a query executed agains my database (just one line & multple fields)

Now I would like to show those datas in my JSP within the formular and then work with each element independently.

This is the code which I'm trying:

```
<form name="SolveName" action="Controller?value=<c:out value="${Node}"/>&operation=SolveProblem" method="POST">
    <table border=1 width="30%" name="fails">

     <c:forEach var="item"  items="${Names}">
         <td></td>
         <td><input type="submit" name="sSubmit" value="Fix it" /></td>
         <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
       <tr>
           <c:set var="element" value="${item}${'.string'}${i}" />
           <td><c:out value="${element}" /></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="fail" value="${item.element}" /></td>
       </tr>
      </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
  </table>

</form>
```

obviously it doesn't work, I got as a result in each row:

```
  javabeans.ListElevenElements@43a71f2e.string1
  javabeans.ListElevenElements@43a71f2e.string2
  javabeans.ListElevenElements@43a71f2e.string3
  so on till 10...
```

Then my question is; There is anyway to get each "string" name element from a variable?

Comment: What is the datatype of ${item}?

Comment: The dataType for each element within the ArrayList is string.

Comment: In case you don't explain what data class behind your jsp is, as rightfully stated by @developerwjk, no one will be able to offer help. Despite that you claim to access a list element of type string, you try to access a property string1 etc. and these two options obviously are self-excluding.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didnt undestand the question. Behind of my JSP the class are Strings: [Laura, james, Ricky, Paul, ....so on...]

Comment: Sorry, forget the last comment.  ${item} do reference to each element inside of ${Names} which are type string. value="${item}${'.string'}${i}"-- with this sytanx what I'm trying to do is concatenate both vriable in order to get as many String as exist in the ${Name} ArraList